# Scale docker service with the number of available CPU cores

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am using a docker swarm for a CPU intensive computing application. Every container runs the same single-threaded application. Of course, the more containers are available, the faster the overall computation is, but only up to the number of available CPU cores. So, on a node with 8 cores, there should be 8 running containers.

However, nodes join and leave the swarm dynamically, so the overall number of available CPU cores in the swarm varies. How can the service be scaled automatically, to reflect this?

Remark: My application relies on an overlay network, so as far as I know, using services instead of manual handling of containers is the preferred approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that came to my mind is to regularly check the connected nodes and create a service for every node with the appropriate number of replicas. It might not be a very elegant solution, but at least it works with the following Python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import docker

def rescale(service_prefix,service_arguments):
    client = docker.from_env()
    service_names = [s.name for s in client.services.list()]

    for node in client.nodes.list():
        # Only handle ready nodes
        if node.attrs['Status']['State'] != 'ready':
            continue

        service_name = service_prefix+node.id
        if service_name not in service_names:
            # Service does not exist -> Create it
            cpus = node.attrs['Description']['Resources']['NanoCPUs']/1000000000
            print("Creating service %s with %i replicas"%(service_name,cpus))
            mode={'Replicated':{'Replicas':int(cpus)}}
            constraints=['node.id==%s'%node.id]
            client.services.create(name=service_name, mode=mode, constraints=constraints, **service_arguments)
        else:
            # Continue running this service
            service_names.remove(service_name)

    # Remove services of no longer existing nodes
    for service in service_names:
        print("Removing service %s"%service)
        client.services.get(service).remove()

rescale(service_prefix="evaluation_",
        service_arguments={'image':'imagename','networks':['swarmnet']})
```